# Two equal max values in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with some numbers(score) and repeating ID. I want to get the maximum value for each of the ID.
I used this function

```
top = aggregate(df$score, list(df$ID),max)
```

This returned me a top dataframe with maximum values corresponding to each ID.

But it so happens that for one of the ID, we have two EQUAL max value. But this function is ignoring the second value.

Is there any way to retain BOTH the max values.?

For Example:

df

```
ID   score
1    12
1    15
1    1
1    15
2    23
2    12
2    13
```

The above function gives me this:
top

```
ID    Score
1     15
2     23
```

I need this:
top

```
ID   Score
1    15
1    15
2    23
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the maximum value for _both_ `ID` and `score`? It is, for each unique pair of `ID` and `score`?

Comment: This is my dataset for better understanding. Added above!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend `data.table` as Chris mentioned (good for speed, but steeper learning curve).
Or if you don't want `data.table` you could use `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(ID), subset, score==max(score))
# same as ddply(df, .(ID), function (x) subset(x, score==max(score)))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can convert to a `data.table`:

```
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[, .SD[score == max(score)], by=ID]
```

Comment: I am a newbie, I don't seem to have data.table instead I have data.frame.table. But this doesn't seem to have any argument "by="

Comment: `install.packages("data.table")`

Comment: Is there any way I can do this without converting my data frame into any other format?

Comment: wait for someone to come up with a base `R` solution then :p

Comment: then you are going to have to give us a more comprehensive example demonstrating what you want

Comment: @AftabKhan I entered the data manually as you posted it and my solution worked. You will have to post your data otherwise.

Comment: Let me recheck again and get back to u!

Comment: Still not working buddy, is there any way I can mail u the exact dataset?

Comment: You can use the `dput` function and post it, if it will fit.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `dplyr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(score == max(score))
```

Otherwise, to build on what you have done, we can use a sneaky property of `merge` on your "top" dataframe, see the following example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,5,2), score = c(5,5,2,6))

top_df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2), score = c(5,6))

merge(df1, top_df)
```

which gives:

```
  ID score
1  1     5
2  1     5
3  2     6
```

Answer (score 3):

Staying with a `data.frame`:

```
df[unlist(by(df, df$ID, FUN=function(D) rownames(D)[D$score == max(D$score)] )),]
#  ID score
#2  1    15
#4  1    15
#5  2    23
```

This works because `by` splits `df` into a list of data.frames on the basis of `df$ID`, but retains the original `rownames` of `df` ( see `by(df, df$ID, I)` ). Therefore, returning the `rownames` of each `D` subset corresponding to a max `score` value in each group can still be used to subset the original `df`.

Comment: Solution is perfect. But Im kinda sticking with ddply solution..:P
This will take me longer to comprehend! Thanx anyways..!

Answer (score 0):

A simple base R solution:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
                 score = c(12, 15, 1, 15, 23, 12, 13))
```

Several options:

```
df[df$score %in% tapply(df$score, df$ID, max), ] 
df[df$score %in% aggregate(score ~ ID, data = df, max)$score, ]
df[df$score %in% aggregate(df$score, list(df$ID), max)$x, ]
```

Output:

```
  ID score
2  1    15
4  1    15
5  2    23
```

Using `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('SELECT df.ID, score FROM df 
  JOIN (SELECT ID, MAX(score) AS score FROM df GROUP BY ID)
  USING (score)')
```

Output:

```
  ID score
2  1    15
4  1    15
5  2    23
```

Comment: All the base options you gave, outputs all the rows with value greater than the minimum value.! Not what is desired.

Comment: I would ignore sqldf since I would have to learn and comprehend SQL commands.

Comment: @ Aftab Khan Have you run the code in R? The base options do return the right output, not greater than the minimum. Otherwise, in the example I provided, the output would include the first row too: (ID:1, score:12) . It is exactly the same data frame and output you demanded.

Comment: I did run the code on my data set and it did not produce the desired output.!

Comment: My code provides the desired output for the problem at hand and I provided a reproducible example. Others could corroborate that.

Comment: Maybe there was some mistake in my execution, though ive double checked! Cheers!